# Error occurred while building debian package for c++ source file

Tags: c++, linux, debian

when I am trying to build `.deb` package using command

```
dpkg-deb --build /home/hduser/Desktop/debpack/usr/bin/hw
```

on terminal,it gives error

> dpkg-deb: error: failed to open package info file `/home/hduser/Desktop/debpack/usr/bin/hw/DEBIAN/control' for reading: Not a directory

`./hw` is executable file of below c++ source file..

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout << "Hello world\n";
  return 0;
}
```

I am tried a lot, but keep failing.

Comment: Something is not clear, you are saying hw is an executable but the error message says it is a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just an executable is not enough to create a package, you should create appropriate file hierarchy.

1. create a root directory, lets name it ***hello-pack***.

   `mkdir hello-pack`
2. create a ***control*** file, the path would be for the file is ***hello-pack/DEBIAN/control***.

   `mkdir hello-pack/DEBIAN`

   `touch hello-pack/DEBIAN/control`

   Content of the file can be the following:

> Package: helloworld
>
> Version: 1.0
>
> Maintainer: Your-Name
>
> Architecture: all
>
> Description: hello world

3. copy your executable to wherever you want it to be located, (I am thinking that you want it to be under ***usr/bin***, if so do the followings, if not create your own directories)

   `mkdir hello-pack/usr/bin`

   `cp hw hello-pack/usr/bin`

Then create package with the command `dpkg-deb --build hello-pack`. It will create the package to the same directory where your root directory exist with the same name and with ***.deb*** extension. You can use `-i` option to install the package.

Comment: By the way, control file should be in /home/hduser/Desktop/debpack/DEBIAN

Comment: Yeah man..but I am not  understanding why it gives me error `dpkg-deb: error: failed to open package info file /home/hduser/Desktop/debpack/usr/bin/hw`

Comment: Because you have wrong file hierarchy, try `dpkg-deb --build /home/hduser/Desktop/debpack` and don't forget that your executable hw is under `/home/hduser/Desktop/debpack/usr/bin` and **control file** is under `/home/hduser/Desktop/debpack/DEBIAN`